# how to put 2 parameters in 1 column?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SprInvoerGemeente]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @postcode varchar(4),
    @naam_gemeente varchar(105),
    --@postcode_gemeente varchar(105)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    insert into postcode (postcode, naam_gemeente, postcode_gemeente) 
    values(@postcode ,@naam_gemeente,@postcode ""  @naam_gemeente)
END
```

in the values section i try to put the 2 parameters `(@postcode, @naam_gemeente)` in 1 column, can somebody help me with the syntax please???

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation operator `+`:

```
insert into postcode (postcode, naam_gemeente, postcode_gemeente) 
    values(@postcode ,@naam_gemeente,@postcode + " " + @naam_gemeente)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [concatenate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) them into a single value:

```
values(@postcode ,@naam_gemeente,@postcode + ' ' + @naam_gemeente)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i get a message" invalid column name"


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 insert into postcode (postcode, naam_gemeente, postcode_gemeente) 
 values(@postcode ,@naam_gemeente,@postcode + " " + @naam_gemeente)

END
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SprInvoerGemeente, Line 16
Invalid column name ' '.

Comment: @Rachid - My bad. You can't use double quotes (`"`) for strings in SQL. Use single quotes (`'`) instead. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

In your `values` you need to add a `+` to concatenate the two columns together:

```
insert into postcode (postcode, naam_gemeente, postcode_gemeente)     
     values (@postcode, @naam_gemeente,@postcode + " " + @naam_gemeente)
```